# IBAction is not being triggered

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have created a framework which shows a small window to inform the user about the current progress of a running process.
This window comes with an own window controller. This window controller contains some properties which have been bound to some properties of a `NSProgressIndicator` control as well as a boolean property bound to the `Enabled` property of a button which shall enable the user to cancel the current action.

The button has been wired up with an `IBAction` within my `File's Owner`. The type of my `File's Owner` has been set to my custom window controller. The bindings for the `NSProgressIndicator` work fine (the bar is being filled when the values have been updated) but the binding for the `NSButton` does not.

Neither the `Enabled` property changed (though the bound property has been changed) nor does the button trigger it's `IBAction` method.

Here's some code:

Window Controller header:

```
@property SEL cancelActionSelector;
@property id cancelDelgate;
@property double currentValue;
@property double maxValue;
@property BOOL cancelAvailable;

- (IBAction)cancelClicked:(id)sender;
```

Window Controller implementation:

```
- (IBAction)cancelClicked:(id)sender
{
    if (self.cancelDelgate && self.cancelActionSelector && [self.cancelDelgate respondsToSelector:self.cancelActionSelector])
    {
        NSLog(@"User requested update cancellation.");
        [self.cancelDelgate performSelector:self.cancelActionSelector];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"User requested update cancellation. Could not perform due to missing target (delegate: %@, selector: %p", self.cancelDelgate, self.cancelActionSelector);
    }
}
```

`currentValue` and `maxValue` have been bound to the `NSProgressIndicator` control (works) and `cancelAvailable` as well as the `cancelClicked` action have been bound to an `NSButton`. Nothing I have done with the button works. Does anybody have a clue why?

**Update:**

The `Enabled` binding of the button works. So it is just the action which does not work. I just tried to bind the `target` property to the window controller itself. Doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
The issue was a result of the way I have localized that framework. 
My UI has been localized by duplicating the original XIB for the german language and I didn't notice that I have to wire up the button with its `IBAction` for each localized UI separately.

So you have to connect the controls with their corresponding actions within each localized XIB on its own.